# Compile error while Short class instance creation expressions

Tags: java

I know it might be very stupid question. I don't understand why Compile error while Short class instance creation expressions.It works with integer perfect but not with short.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

            short i=(short)1 - (short)2;  //It works
            new Integer((int)1-(int)2); //It works
            new Short((short)2 - (short)1); //The constructor Short(int) is undefined
    }
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: in simple words the outcome of any arithmetic operation can be either integer or bigger data type like float or double if it includes any operand of that type. so you need to case the result. that's it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2) :

> If an integer operator other than a shift operator has at least one
>   operand of type long, then the operation is carried out using 64-bit
>   precision, and the result of the numerical operator is of type long.
>   If the other operand is not long, it is first widened (§5.1.5) to type
>   long by numeric promotion (§5.6).
>
> Otherwise, the operation is carried out using 32-bit precision, and
>   the result of the numerical operator is of type int. If either operand
>   is not an int, it is first widened to type int by numeric promotion.

So the result of `(short)2 - (short)1` is an `int`.

Simply use

```
new Short((short) (2 - 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

All primitive integer expressions are `int`s (except `long`s) unless you explicitly cast them. You need to cast the *whole* expression as a `short`:

```
new Short((short)(2 - 1));
```

Note that in:

```
short i = (short) 1 - (short) 2;
```

`(short) 1 - (short) 2` is in fact an int; but the JVM "downcasts" it to a `short` given that this is the type your declaration requires.

Comment: Yes, but those are decimal numbers, not integer numbers.

Comment: For decimal default arithmetic operation result is double

Answer (score 0):

The Java language specification defines exactly how integer numbers are represented and how integer arithmetic expressions are to be evaluated. Above expression return int because for integers values arithmetic operation are performed as integers (except long). If you need short as constructor argument you should use following expression: `(short)(2-1)`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from reading, I come to this conclusion.

`short i=(short)1 - (short)2;  //It works`

The compiler will implicitly do a narrowing conversion for an assignment expression if the right hand operand is a compile-time constant of type byte, short, char or int and the value falls within the range of the variable on the left and the variable is of type byte, short, or char.

`new Short((short)2 - (short)1); //The constructor Short(int) is undefined`

The same is not true for the parameters of a method or constructor. The designers of the Java programming language felt that implicit narrowing conversions of method and constructor arguments would add unnecessary complexities to the process of resolving overloaded method calls.

Comment: That's not the right conclusion. Read my answer. Basically `(short)1 - (short)2` is an int, and those casts are totally useless. What's important is to cast the **result** to a short so that the `Short` constructor can accept it.